# Can I use the Mantel test to check independence between samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, autocorrelation, assumptions

I have data from an experimental design in which I doubt there is independence between samples. My first idea is to use the Mantel test to look for spatial autocorrelation between the measured variable (abundance of a pest species) in the different plots.

In case the Mantel test is >0.05 and I cannot reject the null hypothesis. Could I say the samples are not spatially autocorrelated and therefore, my data meet the independence assumption? Why?